# Deploy to iPhone Device doesn't work with Xamarin.iOS, "No iOS signing identities match"

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to deploy my app to my iPhone device in order to debug it (Automatic provision) but it says "No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile". I am able to deploy apps from Xcode to the iPhone device.

Comment: google `Xamarin.iOS No iOS signing identities match`.

Comment: Already tried that :/ Didn't help ..

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your `bundle identifier` in your app match your `app id` on the [portal](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2Faccount%2Fresources%2F&rv=1).

The app id listed on the portal should match (either exactly or with a wildcard `*`).  Then in your `info.plist`, it should match your `CFBundleIdentifier`. That's what it uses to match provisioning profiles.

For more detail, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=windows .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I'm really confused about the bundle identifier, app id and the CFBundleIdentifier and how they're connected to each other .. My bundle Identifier on info.plist is com.companyname.appname.
I found the App id on the apple developer portal, I would be really happy if you can elaborate the steps for me.

Comment: The `BundleIdentifier` and `CFBundleIdentifier` both stand for the `bundle identifier` in the `info.plist` file and are the same thing. And `App ID` is a portal expression and represents the same thing as the above two keywords( `BundleIdentifier` and `CFBundleIdentifier`). In addition, please change the default `com.companyname.appname` to another one, it could be used by someone else.

Comment: Hi Jessie, thanks for assisting me. I changed it to another one and the same error persists... What exactly and how do I need to make sure that it's the same in my project?
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked document [Device provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/)? This document provides detailed guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Some times VS cannot create certificate automatically. It can be solved by creating new Xcode project using your bundle ID and make sure it run from Xcode debug

Answer (score 0):

We have just faced this issue today, our Development Certificate has expired.

Regenerate a new certificate and new provisioning profiles resolved the issue